# mongodb replacing the current obj (update)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update an obj in a collection with update query, but without to define field by field ... to get the obj(json) as is, in replace of what there is currently there.

this is what I tried to do,

```
function(userObj, callback) {
      usersCollection.update( { _id : ObjectId(context.user._id) }, userObj, function(err, updatedUser) {
        if(err)
          callback(err);

          console.log('user was updated - here is the new db obj', updatedUser);
          callback(err, updatedUser);
      });
    }
```

and this is the error I received,

```
/Users/x/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
    at new ObjectID (/Users/x/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:38:11)
    at ObjectID (/Users/x/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:29:42)
    at Object.module.exports.db.users.update (/Users/x/db.js:54:39)
    at /Users/x/login.js:91:30
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/x/db.js:42:9)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/x/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:178:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Promise.emit (/Users/x/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/Users/x/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at Promise.resolve (/Users/x/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:126:15)
```

logging the `context.user._id` returns the real user's id (that was gaven from mongo) which is `55293e1d2af8dc9ed83141b6`

Comment: The context.user._id being passed is an invalid ObjectId. Try logging the value to check what is being passed.

Comment: 55293e1d2af8dc9ed83141b6

its the user's id (that was gaven by mongo)

Comment: try deleting _id from userObj like, `delete userObj._id` before update

Comment: also update should be like `.update ({_id: ....}, {$set: userObj} ..` unless there is some wrappers.

Comment: yep, deleting the `_id` from `userObj` was the problem. if I could create you'r comment as answer I'd .. thanks you

Answer (score 0):

According to [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html), you don't have to convert the `_id` field to `Objectid` in the update call.

So the following code should work fine.

```
function(userObj, callback) {
  usersCollection.update( { _id : context.user._id }, userObj, function(err, updatedUser) {
    if(err)
      callback(err);

      console.log('user was updated - here is the new db obj', updatedUser);
      callback(err, updatedUser);
  });
}
```

I have checked the typescript implementation in one of my projects where I have used _id as normal string and the code works fine. Check [github source code](https://github.com/reise/reise/blob/master/server/providers/logs.provider.ts) `updateLog` function for further details.

Let me know if I'm missing something.

I hope this helps :)